# How uploading site icon using theme 2022 and wordpress 6.2.1

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to upload a site icon in wordpress using 2022 theme. It doesn't show the option for uploading. My wordpress is 6.2.1. Can you help?
It looks like the installed version of wordpress doesn't allow all options of the theme. Do you have any advice about this? anyway to find settings to enable the option to upload site icon?

I watched different videos but they all assumed that the option of uploading was there

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.